# Do role tokens trigger celebration?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Do role tokens like young hero count as a nonland permanent entering the battlefield for [Celebration](https://scryfall.com/search?q=keyword%3Acelebration&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name) triggering?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, role tokens are non-land permanents and count towards Celebration.**

Role tokens are token enchantments, so they are non-land permanents.

> 303.7. Some Aura enchantments also have the subtype “Role.”

Role tokens are created much like any other token; they trigger all applicable ETB abilities.

> 111.1. Some effects put tokens onto the battlefield.